# sparklyr - error after installation

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I'm very happy with the easy Installation of sparklyr.

```
spark_install(version = "2.1.0", hadoop_version = "2.7")
```

> Installation complete.

But after the installtion I want to connect spark I got the following error message. The Folder C:/spark doesn't exist, because RStudio installed the order for spark under my User.

```
 > sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
```

> Created default hadoop bin directory under: C:\spark\tmp\hadoop Error
>   in spark_version_from_home(spark_home, default = spark_version) :
>   Failed to detect version from SPARK_HOME or SPARK_HOME_VERSION. Try
>   passing the spark version explicitly. In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In dir.create(hivePath, recursive = TRUE) :   cannot create dir
>   'C:\spark', reason 'Permission denied' 2: In dir.create(hadoopBinPath,
>   recursive = TRUE) :   cannot create dir 'C:\spark', reason 'Permission
>   denied' 3: In file.create(to[okay]) :   cannot create file
>   'C:\spark\tmp\hadoop\bin\winutils.exe', reason 'No such file or
>   directory' 4: running command '"C:\spark\tmp\hadoop\bin\winutils.exe"
>   chmod 777 "C:\spark\tmp\hive"' had status 127 
>   >

Someone know a solution?

EDIT:

I have copy the Folder to C:/spark and now it works. But I get the following error message:

> Created default hadoop bin directory under: C:\spark\tmp\hadoop Error
>   in start_shell(master = master, spark_home = spark_home, spark_version
>   = version,  :    sparklyr does not currently support Spark version: 2.1.0

But this Version is listet under: spark_available_versions()

Which Version is the newest I can install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I habe installed this Version and all works fine:

```
`spark_install(version = "2.0.0", hadoop_version = "2.6")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `SPARK_HOME` is already set in your environment and `sparklyr` is trying to use that rather than the version you installed with `sparklyr`. I would try running `Sys.unsetenv("SPARK_HOME")` before connecting with `master="local"`.